# WebView2 mouse cursor problem on WinUI 3 Desktop project

Tags: c#, .net, webview2, winui-3

I am trying to open some games on WinUI 3 using 1.0.1083-prerelease version of WebView2 Microsoft Edge browser. When try to open some gaming websites such as ev.io it can not lock the mouse cursor and can't play the game. My simple code is as below;

```
<Window
x:Class="WV2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
xmlns:local="using:WV2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <controls:WebView2 x:Name="MyWebView"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="https://ev.io"/>

</Grid>
```

I made lots of search on the web but couldn't find anything.
Does somebody have any idea about it ?

Comment: If you open the webpage in a browser, does it work?

Comment: Yes of course it works. It also works in previous WebView.

Comment: I think you should better post this issue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback